# Is it possible for $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] to not be set?

Tags: php, user-agent, error-log

I've just been looking through a website's `error_log` and one of the error's that has been logged a few times is:

`[21-Jun-2011 12:24:03] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/ukevents/public_html/lib/toro.php on line 130`

The line this pertains to in **toro.php** is:

```
private function ipad_request() {
    return strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad');
}
```

Is it possible for `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to not be set by a HTTP request?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, this a HTTP header sent (or not sent) by client, and you should not rely on it. From php manual:

> Contents of the User-Agent: header from the current request, if there is one

So the correct code would be:

```
private function ipad_request() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Any browser or user-agent can choose not to send the `User-Agent` header. If they do not send that header, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` won't be set.

Use [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to ensure that `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is set.

```
private function ipad_request() {
  if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return false;

  return strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad') !== false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible, but it never happens for a regular request.

All browsers do send a browser string in the request, so any request that arrives without one comes from some other program. Even all well-behaving bots send a browser string, so you don't have to be concerned about not showing up in search engines either.

Answer (score 2):

PHP docs says:

'HTTP_USER_AGENT'
    Contents of the User-Agent: header from the current request, *if there is one*.

(relevant part italicised) so it would appear it might not always be set.

Answer (score 1):

An example where HTTP_USER_AGENT is undefined is if the request coming from GoDaddy's 404 page handler for your site where you have set the handler to be one of your pages.