# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in Magento Enterprise 1.10

Tags: magento

Any ideas why the system.log in magento system is full of this error?

2012-09-04T06:37:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT  in /var/www//app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php on line 588

we are using Magento Enterprise 1.10, when I was goolging for any hints, seems like it may have something to do with the design theme exception in system->configuration...

Answer (score 5):

*This is technically a bug in Magento*, as this variable is assumed to be set when it [in fact may not be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465397/is-it-possible-for-serverhttp-user-agent-to-not-be-set).

Reported here with backlink: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=14194

**Edit: adding simple patch**

```
    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: does it mean we have to "patch" it up ourselves for the time being to prevent this from flooding the log file, correct?

Comment: Yep. Patch code above. This would be an example of a potentially acceptable app/code/local/Mage/ override ;-) - just remember to merge in new changes in a new version.

Comment: @benmarks I am also facing the same issue, it would be great if you can let me know where do I need to place the above mentioned code.