# PHP's eregi to preg_match conversion

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

```
if ((eregi('opera mini', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) == 1)
```

How can I convert this?

```
if ((preg_match('opera mini', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) == 1)
```

The above does not work.

Comment: You don't REGEX which is expensive to find the first occurrence of a string. [`stristr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) would work just fine. And you [shouldn't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465397/is-it-possible-for-serverhttp-user-agent-to-not-be-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the delimeters. I choose to use `/`, others choose `~` or `#`.

```
if ((preg_match('/opera mini/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) == 1)
```

Comment: thx men, it`s work pretty :)